# Speed advantage in combining FFmpeg filters?

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I'm currently using five separate FFmpeg processes to do the following:

1. trim & crop Vid B
2. scale Vid B to height of Vid A
3. combine Vid B & Vid A
4. add a fade-in/fade-out to Combined Vid
5. add an overlay to fade in/out vid

I have them all set to ultrafast but it still takes a long time - about 40 seconds when each video is ~10 seconds long.

I initially explored combining some of the filters but couldn't get it working in the timeframe I had available. I also wasn't sure if the time spent figuring out how to combine all the filters would pay off in a faster processing time.

Any thoughts/insights from you brilliant FFmpeg gurus? Would this speed up processing, and if so, should I combine all the commands together or are there some I should combine and others I should leave separate?

Here are my current commands, all of which are working:

```
// trimming 200ms off begining of vid B + cropping frame (note that I have previously retrieved dimensions and duration of both videos with ffprobe)
1. `ffmpeg -i vidB.mov -ss 200 -t ${vidB.duration} -async 1 -filter:v "crop=iw:${vidB.croppedHeight}:0:${vidB.offset}" -preset ultrafast -c:a copy croppedVidB.mov`

// scale Vid B up to Vid A's height
2. `ffmpeg -i croppedVidB.mov -vf scale=-2:${vidA.height} vidBScaled.mov`

// combine videos
3. `ffmpeg -i vidA.mov -i vidBScaled.mov -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] hstack=inputs=2[v]; [0:a][1:a]amix[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -preset ultrafast -ac 2 combined.mov`

// add fade in & out
4. `ffmpeg -i combined.mov -sseof -1 -copyts -i combined.mov -filter_complex "[1]fade=out:0:30[t];[0][t]overlay,fade=in:0:30[v]; anullsrc,atrim=0:1[at];[0][at]acrossfade=d=1,afade=d=1[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset ultrafast -shortest fadeInOut.mov`

// add overlay
5. `ffmpeg -i fadeInOut.mov -i overlay.png -filter_complex overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10 -codec:a copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 overlay.mov`
```

Thanks in advance for your thoughts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do everything in one command:

```
ffmpeg -i vidA.mov -ss 200 -t ${vidB.duration} -i vidB.mov -i overlay.png -filter_complex "[1]crop=iw:${vidB.croppedHeight}:0:${vidB.offset},scale=-2:${vidA.height}[right];[0][right]hstack=inputs=2,fade=t=in:duration=1,fade=t=out:start_time=${vidB.duration - 1}:duration=1[bg];[bg][2]overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10:format=auto,format=yuv420p[v];[0:a][1:a]amix,afade=t=in:duration=1,afade=t=out:start_time=${vidB.duration - 1}:duration=1[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -ac 2 -movflags +faststart output.mp4
```

Note the `${vidB.duration - 1}`: it was my lazy method of showing you need to subtract 1 second with `bc` or similar.

Comment: Thanks! Looking forward to trying this. Will it speed up the processing?

Comment: @lach_codes It will most likely be faster, it avoids several instances of [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss), and it also avoids the temporary intermediate files.

Comment: Hey @llogan, I ran this command but there's no video in the output, just audio:

```ffmpeg -i vidA.mov -ss 200 -t 4.816667 -i vidB.mov -i logo.png -filter_complex "[1]crop=iw:1214:0:352.5,scale=-2:1920[right];[0][right]hstack=inputs=2,fade=t=in:duration=1,fade=t=out:start_time=3.816667:duration=1[bg];[bg][2] overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10:format=auto,format=yuv420p[v];[0:a][1:a]amix,afade=t=in:duration=1,afade=t=out:start_time=3.816667:duration=1[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -c:a aac -ac 2 -movflags +faststart output.mov```

Do you know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @lach_codes Works for me. Show the **complete** log from your command. You can use a pastebin site and provide the link in a comment.

Comment: @lach_codes Your `-ss` value exceeds the duration of the input. You should describe what you are trying to do. It will be better then me blindly trying to work with your command without knowing what you want to achieve.

Comment: 4.816667 was the duration I got from an ffprobe on the input file. I'm trying to trim off 200ms from the beginning.

Comment: @lach_codes You declared 200 seconds. See [time duration syntax](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#time-duration-syntax).

Comment: Hey @llogan - can you let me know how I would change this if I needed to scale the height of vidA up to the height of vidB instead of vice versa? I have tried several ways but none of them are working. Here is the latest I tried: https://pastebin.com/QNNqrm4r Thank you!